# Do we have to always prune trees in decision tree method?

Tags: cart

Do we have to always prune the tree in decision tree? what if the unpruned tree with cross validation produces better results than pruned tree ?

Answer (score 2):

In practice yes, but there might be some corner cases where pruning is harmful and should be avoided.

For example, you have 50 binary variables $v_i$ (0 or 1). You construct a binary class $c \leftarrow \sum_i v_i > 30$ that is a direct consequence of your variables.

Predicting this class is possible with perfect accuracy if you allow the tree to use all variables (disable pruning) because the class outcome is deterministic. Normal implementations of decision trees would prune and have less than perfect accuracy.

Realistic data-sets do not allow for deterministic class prediction though.